# To make a blue moon, what element does it need?

Tags: hard-science, moons, astronomy, geology, unusual-color

We know that Mars has a reddish color, because its ground consists of iron-based compounds. The moon is grey-whiteish because it consists mostly of silicon-based compounds.

What element should the moon in my world have in order to have a blue color?

I thought about cobalt-based compounds, but naturally this element is silver-grey.

Comment: Does your moon have an atmosphere?

Comment: @L.Dutch I prefer moon without any atmosphere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need an element, you need a mineral.

Certain elements do tend to make things a certain colour, for example nickel will make minerals green, manganese pink, and cobalt purple.

The fact that cobalt itself is a metal is irrelevant. Whatever "element" you have will not be metallic, it will be as a cation (or anion) in the silicates.

So your question should be rephrased to:

> **What element do I need to make the silicates the moon is made of, blue?**

You have several options.

1. Add sodium and chlorine, in order to make [sodalite](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sodalite&ia=images&iax=images): Na<sub>8</sub>Al<sub>6</sub>Si<sub>6</sub>O<sub>24</sub>Cl<sub>2</sub> (with the other elements already abundantly present on the moon).

[image]

2. Sodium and water, at high pressure and then somehow expose those rocks on the surface. You will have [glaucophane](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=glaucophane&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images): Na<sub>2</sub>(Mg<sub>3</sub>Al<sub>2</sub>)Si<sub>8</sub>O<sub>22</sub>(OH)2. This is the main ingredient of the terrestrial rocks known as blueschists:

[image]

3. Tons more aluminium, so then you can stabilise corundum (Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>). When combined with the already abundant iron and titanium as trace elements, you end up with blue corundum. Also known as sapphire when in gem quality:

[image]

This should get you started. Other things you might consider are potassium and whatever makes [amazonite](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=blue%20feldspar&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images) (potassium feldspar) green-blue. [Copper](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=azurite&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images) is also a good one, but the blue requires water that isn't common on the Moon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.